# How to extract values from survfit object

Tags: r, extract, survival-analysis

I've created this model:

```
model <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~c$sex)
model
```

and the output is:

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ c$sex)

             records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
c$sex=female      15    15      15      8    720     517      NA
c$sex=male        28    28      28     23    234     145     712
```

So, I want to extract the median for males and the same for females, but have no idea how to do it.
Here are my attempts to do it:

```
>model$median
NULL

>summary(model)$table[, "median"]
c$sex=female c$sex=male 
       720.0            234.5
```

I want each one of the values alone ("720" and "234.5"), can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `summary(model)$table[, "median"][1]` for female and `summary(model)$table[, "median"][2]` for male? That said, guessing `summary(model)$table[, "median"]` is a vector.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, is it more like `summary(model)$table["median"]` if there is no stratification, i.e. one KM curve and not multiple curves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This also works:

```
> library(survMisc)
> fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
> median(fit)
                median
x=Maintained        31
x=Nonmaintained     23
```

And without the names (i.e. remove the structure of a `data.frame`):

```
> unname(unlist(median(fit)))
[1] 31 23
```

It's nice if you also want the confidence interval (default is 'log'):

```
> median(fit, CI=TRUE)
                median lower upper
x=Maintained        31    13    NA
x=Nonmaintained     23     5    43
```

Comment: It's easier this way, I ask myself why didn't I thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Trying your example throws the error `Error in xi == xj : comparison of these types is not implemented`. Actually, I don't see any `survMisc::median()` function available. Am I doing it wrong or has the library changed ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel +1, library has changed.

Answer (score 16):

You've already got it. All you are seeing printed to screen are the `names` attributes of the length 2 vector.

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
summary(fit)$table
#                records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
#x=Maintained         11    11      11      7     31      18      NA
#x=Nonmaintained      12    12      12     11     23       8      NA

#  Access first value like any other vector
summary(fit)$table[,'median'][1]
#x=Maintained 
#          31
```

To print without names use `unname()`...

```
unname(summary(fit)$table[,'median'])
# [1] 31 23
```

But you do not need to `unname()` them to use them as a numeric value, that is just an aesthetic desire...

```
sum( summary(fit)$table[,'median'] )
[1] 54
```

For further *proof* (!) that it is a vector use `str()`...

```
str(summary(fit)$table[,'median'])
# Named num [1:2] 31 23
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x=Maintained" "x=Nonmaintained"
```

Comment: Well, that was simple... Thank you

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as it does not use an additional package.